# FTP permissions

Tags: permissions, ftp

I am running Ubuntu 8.04 and have proftpd server running on it. All the permissions are setup fine except I cannot overwrite files (I have to delete and then upload - really annoying). I am not sure what the problem is. The owner of all files/folders is my username and the group is root (this could be the problem?)

Here is what the permissions look like: rwxr-xr-x

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In the config file (probably in /etc/proftpd.conf), check the AllowOverwrite flag. To enable overwrite, it should be:

```
AllowOverwrite on
```